# Tensorflow object detection gives No module named 'deployment'

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train a custom object detection module using object detection api. I have put everything together and tried to train the module using 'Google Colab'. When I try to train the module it gives this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/trainer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from deployment import model_deploy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deployment'
```

I also execute the blow code segment which is equivalent to `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/models/research/slim/')
```

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Copy 'deployment' folder in 'slim'. Then paste it to 'site-packages' folder of your python environment
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Google Colab,

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/models/research/:/models/research/slim/'
```

this one works..